# Export Oracle DB Schema structure with trigger and functions code

Tags: oracle, csv, export, structure

I would like to create a scheduled task which export my DB structure with indexes, functions, triggers, ... in a csv file.
The goal is to be able to compare db structure together after importing the csv in SQL server.

Comment: DO you want to compare PLSQL functions, triggers with TSQL  counterparts in SQL server?